# VS2008 switching between formatting logic

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, format

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I'm currently working with WPF and I'm using

*Edit->Format Document*

to **format my source code**.

The problem is that I want to have formatting set total differently for style and for Controls themselves.
Which means that I have to switch formatting logic every half an hour through this menu:

*Tools->Options->Text Editor->XAML*

Is there any way to define **these 2 formatting logic and switch between them** more effectively ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a macro to modify your settings, add a toolbar button to invoke it. easy peasy. ;-)

Comment: Yes.. this is obviously the only one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, Nope.

Tools like resharper offer their own kind of formatting (through 'code cleanup') but I'm not sure that helps you.

Comment: It's possible but I don't want to install Resharper as it slows down the VS.

Comment: Indeed, it does slow down VS a little, but it speeds up the Programmer a lot. I run R# and CodeRush/Refactor at the same time. ;-)